# Why doesn't `this.state.text = "text"` in a constructor work in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Why do we have to set it to an object like `this.state = {text: "text"}`. Isn't doing `this.state.text = "text"` the same? Clearly it's not as the first example works and second doesn't. Why is that? Thanks!

Comment: state is immutable in react. I know its crazy

Comment: First of all you must not modify the state directly, always use `setState` or you can face unexpected behavior

Comment: Has to be an object existing for you to assign a property to is why

Comment: @velimir wrong, the OP is talking about *in the constructor* ...

Comment: @charlieftl but why doesnt React initialize the state property inside of the Component constructor?

Comment: @Jonas Wilms - my bad, missed that part

Comment: I can't reproduce your case though, `
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {};
    this.state.test = "Test";
  }` that works just fine

Comment: @VelimirTchatchevsky OP is asking why it doesn't work without first assigning empty object like you did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if anyone actually read your question, but from the docs "The only place where you can assign this.state is the constructor". https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly

You are having a different problem, `this.state = { foo: 'bar' };` is okay in the constructor, but `this.state.foo = 'bar'` won't work because `this.state` is undefined.  If you tried `this.state = {}` and then `this.state.foo = 'bar'` it should work for you.

Comment: I have read it correctly. Thus, in my answer, used `state={}` and then `state.text='test'` which usage is wrong. But surprised some din't understand my post

Comment: @BhojendraRauniyar Sorry I wasn't specifically responding to you, there was another answer that deleted their comments, but was mainly talking about the comments to OP, but your answer incorrectly tells OP not to mutate the state but you SHOULD mutate it in the constructor.  You should not call setState in the constructor

Comment: @kyle Is my post so unclear? I'm not saying to use setState inside the constructor. But explaining why... anyways, leave it.

Answer (score 0):

React provides us the state to use without mutating it. For eg.

```
this.state.text = 'test' // mutates, it's wrong.
this.setState({text:'test'}) // good to go (without mutating)
```

Thus, you need to define the initial state like:

```
state = {text: 'test'}
```

**But not like,**

```
// obviously state.text is undefined,
// so defining like this
state = {}
state.text = 'test'
```

---

Don't confuse with: (Both are same)

```
state = {} // inside class without constructor (ES7)
this.state = {} // inside constructor
```

---

> The state contains data specific to this component that may change over time. The state is user-defined, and it should be a plain JavaScript object.
>
> If some value isn’t used for rendering or data flow (for example, a timer ID), you don’t have to put it in the state. Such values can be defined as fields on the component instance.

Visit [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) for more information.

Comment: None of this has anything to do with the constructor or OP's question

Comment: Right...this is all confusing and doesn't address OP's question about *"in the constructor"*. You don't use `setState` in constructor

Comment: I now knew, you get my post totally wrong. Sorry if I couldn't make it clear enough. But my intention was to make this clear why setState is used? Obviously not  to mutate and this way even in the constructor, we should define like that... Please read my post carefully.